# jQuery Ajax Form submit - Disable on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

Ajax form submit usability. when i submit the form i wanna diable the form to be submited till the previous submission happens. can i do this by just disabling the input or text area or should i disable the submit button too ?

Comment: Better to disable submit button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable form-submission by letting its onsubmit-handler return false:

```
<form onsubmit="return false">...
```

Of course you would have a javascript-function which decides whether to submit or not:

```
<form onsubmit="return myDecisionFunction()">...
```

The decision-function in your case could look like this:

```
var submissionEnabled = true;
function myDecisionFunction() {
   if (submissionEnabled) {
       submissionEnabled = false;
       return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
}
```

And after the ajax-response came in, you enable it again:

```
submissionEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this by disabling the submit button.

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#form").submit();
})
```

Comment: What if the user press enter on the form?

Comment: This solution depends on the developer knowing beforehand which button is on charge of performing the submit. The form submit process can, however, be initiated by several ways... enter, code, click, space-bar.